# Python Multiprocessing, Trouble Terminating Processes on Restart and Preventing Zombies

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, python-3.5

**Solution:**

Thanks to Rick Sanders, adding this function after terminating a process resolves the issue:

[`os.waitpid(pid, options)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.waitpid)

Zombie processes are created when a process is terminated, and unless they are reaped (by requesting exit code). They remain for the purpose that the parent can request it's exit code, and as my script does not truly exit, it's process is replaced by `execv(file, args)`, the parent never requests the exit code and the zombie process is kept. This works on both my OSX and Debian systems.

I am working on a very large script and have recently implemented multiprocessing and IMAP to listen for emails. Before I implemented this I had implemented a restart command that I can enter at command-line to refresh the script after editing, in a nutshell it does this:

```
if ipt = ':rs':
    execv(__file__)
```

It prints out a bunch of crap in interim, though.

I also have a process running in another object, that listens to Google's IMAP server in a While-loop like so:

```
While True:
    mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
    mail.login('myemail@gmail', 'mypassword')
    mail.list()
    mail.select("inbox")

    result, data = mail.uid('search', None, 'All')

    latest_email_uid = data[0].split()[-1] #grabs the most recent email by
                                           #unique id number

    if int(latest_email_uid) != int(last_email_uid): # set earlier from sql                         
                                                     # database
        # do stuff with the mail
    else:
        continue
```

Through watching top, I noticed I was creating zombies when I restarted, so I created a termination function:

```
def process_terminator(self):
    self.imap_listener.terminate()
```

And I called it from restart:

```
if ipt == ':rs':
    self.process_object.terminate()
    execv(__file__)
```

However, the zombie processes still persist. So, after a few hours of work I realized that adding a time.sleep period after calling the function AND either setting a local variable to the process' exitcode OR printing the process' exitcode would allow the process to terminate, even if it was just 0.1 second:

```
if ipt == ':rs':
    self.process_object.terminate()
    time.sleep(.1)
    print(self.process_object.imap_listener.exitcode)
    execv(__file__)
```

This is not the case in OSX, though, simply executing a process' .terminate() function ends the process, however on my debian machine, I HAVE to have a sleep(n) period AND HAVE to refer to a process' exitcode in some form or fashion to prevent it from zombying.

I have also tried using .join, though that hangs up my entire script. I have tried creating variables to have the process break its while loop when (for example) self.terminated = 1, then join, however that does not work either.

I don't have this issue when running exec('quit'), so long as I terminate then process, .join() does not work.

Can someone please point out any misunderstandings on my part? I have tried doing my own research but have not found a sufficient solution, and I am aware that processes should not be explicitly terminated as they will not exit nicely, but I've found no other way after hours of work.

Sorry that I do not have more code to provide, will do my best to provide more if needed, these are just snippets of relevant code from my script (1000+ lines).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might start here:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombie_process.  The parent process has to reap its children when they exit, for example by using waitpid():

[`os.waitpid(pid, options)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.waitpid)

Waits for a particular child process to terminate and returns the pid of the deceased process, or -1 if there is no such child process. On some systems, a value of 0 indicates that there are processes still running.

Comment: Ah, that explains why I must read the exit code before it is removed from the process table. I'll adjust my code and see if this resolves it. Thank you!

Comment: Awesome! This worked:
`def process_terminator(self):
        self.imap_listener.terminate()
        waitpid(self.imap_listener.pid, 0)`
At least on OSX, will try it on my debian system now...